# SourcePollingChannelAdapter create

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I use spring and spring-integration. I need create `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` dynamic for Feed parse, and register in Spring context.

```
      QueueChannel channel = (QueueChannel) context.getBean("rssFeedChannel");
      SourcePollingChannelAdapter adapter = new SourcePollingChannelAdapter();
      adapter.setApplicationContext(context);
      adapter.setBeanName("adapter.1");
      FeedEntryMessageSource source = new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL("https://spring.io/blog.atom"), "news");
      source.setApplicationContext(context);
      source.setBeanName("source");
      adapter.setSource(source);
      adapter.setOutputChannel(channel);
      adapter.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
      adapter.start();
```

And my application config:

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="5000"/>

    <int:channel id="rssFeedChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="40"/>
    </int:channel>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file" mode="APPEND" charset="UTF-8" directory="/tmp/si" filename-generator-expression="'SpringBlog'"/>
    <!-- With this work -->
    <!--<feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news" channel="rssFeedChannel" url="https://spring.io/blog.atom">-->
        <!--<int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>-->
    <!--</feed:inbound-channel-adapter>-->

    <int:transformer input-channel="rssFeedChannel" expression="payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'" output-channel="file"/>
```

but nothing is written to the file. Please help bug.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to watch the message flow.

Comment: `"BeanFactory is required"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must make `FeedEntryMessageSource` as bean, too. The `applicationContext` injection.
2. You forgot to invoke `adapter.afterPropertiesSet()`. BTW the same for the `FeedEntryMessageSource` instance.

From other side, please, share what is in your mind for the reason to go this manual way. Why just don't rely on the standard Inversion of Control principle?

Comment: I need create rss reader. After add new rss url into db, I start new SourcePollingChannelAdapter and read all feeds. After delete url from db, stop SourcePollingChannelAdapter. It is possible to make it easier?

Comment: Good. Makes sense. Please, try to follow with all setters on those components and don't forget about `afterPropertiesSet()`

Comment: `afterPropertiesSet` create only `messageBuilderFactory`. I need get `BeanFactory`.

Comment: I add into service `private @Autowired BeanFactory beanFactory;` and set `BeanFactory` to adaptor and into source)